# libstdc++.so.5: open failed: no such file or directory through ssh

Tags: python, shared-libraries, python-2.4

I am trying to run the plone server from ssh by doing `./bin/instance start` but I am getting this wierd error that says `Python-2.4/bin/python: fatal: libstdc++.so.5: open failed: No such file or directory`. I tried to do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Python-2.4/bin/python` and it says `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Python-2.4/bin/python: is not an identifier`. But when I do  `ls -rtl /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.5`, I can see that `libstdc++.so.5.0.5` is there. I am using `ssh secure shell` in `Windows XP`. Can anyone suggest me how to remove this error?

Comment: Could you give the output of `echo $SHELL` from the shell prompt?

Comment: Then your export line should definitely work, although it should probably be `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: It again gives me error as: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib: is not an identifier

Comment: What OS/Distribution/Version are you running on? Also, what is the output of `ldconfig -p | grep libstdc`. Add this information to the question.

Comment: This command gives me error that sazs ldconfig:not found! I am using ssh secure shell in windows XP! my libstdc is in /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so and when I do echo $PATH I get /usr/bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as follows

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I had my `libstdc` in `/usr/local/lib` and I had to tell the system to find the unavailable libraries here!